# How to extract json from html string php

Tags: php, json, extract

This is the string i have retrieved from youtube mobile site. I want to extract the json  using php.

```
$str = ")]}'{\"conn\": \"wifi\", \"content\": {\"pyv_ping_url\": null, \"subscription_state\": {\"subscribe_url\": {\"url\": \"\\\/channel_post?feature=watch\\u0026action_subscribe=1\", \"channel_id\": \"UCeQEKFH31vvD-InkTGSvCrA\"}, \"show_button\": true, \"is_subscribed\": false}, \"distiller_config\": {\"owner_id\": \"eQEKFH31vvD-InkTGSvCrA\", \"visible\": null, \"pinned_activity\": null, \"channel_id\": \"UCeQEKFH31vvD-InkTGSvCrA\", \"privacy_setting\": \"PUBLIC\", \"query\": \"http:\\\/\\\/www.youtube.com\\\/watch?v=C5tOEBmBAHg\", \"signin_url\": \"https:\\\/\\\/accounts.google.com\\\/ServiceLogin?service=youtube\\u0026passive=true\\u0026uilel=3\\u0026hl=en_US\\u0026ltmpl=mobile\\u0026continue=http%3A%2F%2Fm.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26feature%3Ddistiller%26hl%3Den_US%26next%3D%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DC5tOEBmBAHg%2526client%253Dmv-google%26nomobiletemp%3D1\", \"video_id\": \"C5tOEBmBAHg\", \"debug\": false, \"filter_premod\": false}, \"allow_comments\": true, \"ad_instream\": \"\", \"show_pyv_in_related\": false, \"player_data\":
   {\"fmt_stream_map\": [{\"itag\": \"18\", \"type\": \"video\\\/mp4; codecs=\\\"avc1.42001E, mp4a.40.2\\\"\", \"fallback_host\": \"tc.v6.cache1.c.youtube.com\", \"quality\": \"medium\", \"url\": \"http:\\\/\\\/r4---sn-nau-jhcl.c.youtube.com\\\/videoplayback?ms=au\\u0026itag=18\\u0026mt=1378896627\\u0026app=youtube_mobile\\u0026mv=m\\u0026source=youtube\\u0026sver=3\\u0026expire=1378918433\\u0026sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire\\u0026cp=U0hWTVlMVl9ITUNONl9RRlpFOkV6dktxMFVBYU1Y\\u0026upn=kjDilUW5IQE\\u0026ip=124.43.93.65\\u0026dnc=1\\u0026el=watch\\u0026yms=FcwHm3XWaNY\\u0026ratebypass=yes\\u0026key=yt1\\u0026signature=06D949BF71135F49A3BE9E7A47182B2A61DCF915.5B86FC625C760F1402BC700C660E61CC69684992\\u0026id=0b9b4e1019810078\\u0026fexp=907724%2C906942%2C924606%2C929117%2C929121%2C929906%2C929907%2C929922%2C929127%2C929129%2C929131%2C929930%2C936403%2C925726%2C936310%2C925720%2C925722%2C925718%2C925714%2C929917%2C906945%2C929933%2C920302%2C906842%2C913428%2C919811%2C913563%2C919373%2C930803%2C908536%2C938701%2C931924%2C936308%2C909549%2C900816%2C912711%2C904494%2C904497%2C939903%2C900375%2C900382%2C934507%2C907231%2C936312%2C906001\\u0026ipbits=8\"}, {\"itag\": \"36\", \"type\": \"video\\\/3gpp; codecs=\\\"mp4v.20.3, mp4a.40.2\\\"\", \"fallback_host\": \"tc.v23.cache2.c.youtube.com\", \"quality\": \"small\",
   \"url\": \"http:\\\/\\\/r4---sn-nau-jhcl.c.youtube.com\\\/videoplayback?ms=au\\u0026itag=36\\u0026mt=1378896627\\u0026app=youtube_mobile\\u0026mv=m\\u0026source=youtube\\u0026sver=3\\u0026expire=1378918433\\u0026sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire\\u0026cp=U0hWTVlMVl9ITUNONl9RRlpFOkV6dktxMFVBYU1Y\\u0026upn=kjDilUW5IQE\\u0026ip=124.43.93.65\\u0026dnc=1\\u0026el=watch\\u0026yms=FcwHm3XWaNY\\u0026ratebypass=yes\\u0026key=yt1\\u0026signature=663C16B74F22132913A4E86CFE733CEFC10C18C3.175EA19B37241399C17305FAACEFB07A1C5FB2DD\\u0026id=0b9b4e1019810078\\u0026fexp=907724%2C906942%2C924606%2C929117%2C929121%2C929906%2C929907%2C929922%2C929127%2C929129%2C929131%2C929930%2C936403%2C925726%2C936310%2C925720%2C925722%2C925718%2C925714%2C929917%2C906945%2C929933%2C920302%2C906842%2C913428%2C919811%2C913563%2C919373%2C930803%2C908536%2C938701%2C931924%2C936308%2C909549%2C900816%2C912711%2C904494%2C904497%2C939903%2C900375%2C900382%2C934507%2C907231%2C936312%2C906001\\u0026ipbits=8\"}], \"playability\": \"PLAY_OK\", \"player_type\": \"html5fs\"}, \"subscribe_xsrf_token\": \"V-JkAZNXVIi4gjwRIRaUyy1rqh98MTM3ODk4MzA2MUAxMzc4ODk2NjYx\", \"channel_subscriber_count\": 1445686, \"should_prompt_merge_identity\": false, \"branding\": null, \"sentiment_xsrf_token\": \"rUe1DX9B6S0kBEJwaYYRBQkgw1J8MTM3ODk4MzA2MUAxMzc4ODk2NjYx\", \"ptracking\": \"\\\/\\\/www.youtube.com\\\/ptracking?ptk=brusspup%252Buser\\u0026pltype=content\\u0026oid=3OmbD_Dz3bv1YwNAoU8c6A\\u0026ptchn=brusspup\\u0026video_id=C5tOEBmBAHg\", \"next_url\": \"\\\/related?v=C5tOEBmBAHg\\u0026page=2\", \"allow_ratings\": true, \"video\": {\"user_image_url\": \"\\\/\\\/i1.ytimg.com\\\/i\\\/eQEKFH31vvD-InkTGSvCrA\\\/1.jpg?v=4efb5240\", \"time_created_text\": \"Sep  4, 2013\", \"duration\": \"2:09\", \"view_count\": \"2,767,499\", \"title\": \"Incredible Chemical Reaction!\", \"thumbnail_info\": null, \"comment_count\": 4367, \"dislikes_num\": 1203, \"longform\": false, \"profile_url\": \"\\\/user\\\/brusspup\", \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/C5tOEBmBAHg\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=yvFlZe6HDNoAvIPVEiRBbyEUDAw\", \"likes_num\": 21801, \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=C5tOEBmBAHg\", \"encrypted_id\": \"C5tOEBmBAHg\", \"description\": \"Add me on Facebook. (click LIKE on Facebook to add me) \\nhttp:\\\/\\\/www.facebook.com\\\/brusspup\\n\\n\\nDownload the song in this video:\\nSong name: Monolith\\n\\niTunes\\nhttps:\\\/\\\/itunes.apple.com\\\/us\\\/album\\\/monolith-single\\\/id596457486\\n\\nAmazon\\nhttp:\\\/\\\/www.amazon.com\\\/Monolith\\\/dp\\\/B00B60NGFY\\\/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8\\u0026qid=1378343773\\u0026sr=8-1\\u0026keywords=monolith+brusspup\\n\\nThere are no editing tricks in the video. All of the reactions that you see are uncut and play at the original speed.\\n\\nThis is a classic chemical reaction. It's called the iodine clock reaction. There are several variations of how this chemical reaction can be performed using different chemicals than the ones I used in the video. You can order clock reaction kits from several science related websites. You can also use simple store bought chemicals like vitamin C, iodine, hydrogen peroxide and starch. A quick internet search will turn up multiple ways of performing the experiment.\\n\\nEven though I've played around with the clock reaction experiment before I've always wanted to capture the reaction as the liquid was being poured. To me, this is the most stunning way of demonstrating the reaction.\\n\\nHere's the other version of the clock reaction I made several years ago\\nhttp:\\\/\\\/www.youtube.com\\\/watch?v=qeDhaWEEvfg\", \"length_seconds\": 129, \"public_name\": \"brusspup\"}, \"related_videos\": [{\"duration\": \"2:40\", \"view_count\": \"411,584\", \"title\": \"Amazing Hologram Effect!\", \"thumbnail_info\": {\"posx\": 0, \"posy\": 0, \"stitched\": 1, \"width\": 128, \"height\": 880, \"thumb_height\": 72, \"url\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=WllhvcRH3KM,8tHOVVgGkpk,wvJAgrUBF4w,1yaqUI4b974,hq8j86OenqM,xVyYcAI90jw,vZaRgMOo-Ig,dMuGAmdr8m4,uENITui5_jU,hSorsJ-lRYk,kf1xFCcvadg\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=c99tZpvMiwZDzKB_NwFL5pdZ3QM\", \"thumb_width\": 120}, \"related_feature\": \"relmfu\", \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/WllhvcRH3KM\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=t18Qmilb_rFtwJKJTBCKbaRLQyo\", \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\", \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=WllhvcRH3KM\\u0026feature=relmfu\", \"encrypted_id\": \"WllhvcRH3KM\", \"public_name\": \"brusspup\"}, {\"duration\": \"2:21\", \"view_count\": \"2,589,152\", \"title\": \"Giant Dry Ice Bubble Experiment!\", \"thumbnail_info\": {\"posx\": 0, \"posy\": 80, \"stitched\": 1, \"width\": 128, \"height\": 880, \"thumb_height\": 72, \"url\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=WllhvcRH3KM,8tHOVVgGkpk,wvJAgrUBF4w,1yaqUI4b974,hq8j86OenqM,xVyYcAI90jw,vZaRgMOo-Ig,dMuGAmdr8m4,uENITui5_jU,hSorsJ-lRYk,kf1xFCcvadg\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=c99tZpvMiwZDzKB_NwFL5pdZ3QM\", \"thumb_width\": 120}, \"related_feature\": \"relmfu\", \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/8tHOVVgGkpk\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=hITPLWQ4XEdyqU3OAuySRYY0jRA\", \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\", \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=8tHOVVgGkpk\\u0026feature=relmfu\", \"encrypted_id\": \"8tHOVVgGkpk\", \"public_name\": \"brusspup\"}, {\"duration\": \"3:39\", \"view_count\": \"3,529,768\", \"title\": \"Amazing Resonance Experiment!\", \"thumbnail_info\": {\"posx\": 0, \"posy\": 160, \"stitched\": 1, \"width\": 128, \"height\": 880, \"thumb_height\": 72, \"url\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=WllhvcRH3KM,8tHOVVgGkpk,wvJAgrUBF4w,1yaqUI4b974,hq8j86OenqM,xVyYcAI90jw,vZaRgMOo-Ig,dMuGAmdr8m4,uENITui5_jU,hSorsJ-lRYk,kf1xFCcvadg\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=c99tZpvMiwZDzKB_NwFL5pdZ3QM\", \"thumb_width\": 120}, \"related_feature\": \"relmfu\", \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/wvJAgrUBF4w\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=jNtSWzQ8HbjFb5KQ27wggqmLmlc\", \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\", \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=wvJAgrUBF4w\\u0026feature=relmfu\", \"encrypted_id\": \"wvJAgrUBF4w\", \"public_name\": \"brusspup\"}, {\"duration\": \"8:20\", \"view_count\": \"334,912\", \"title\": \"Resonance Experiment! (Full Version - With Tones)\", \"thumbnail_info\": {\"posx\": 0, \"posy\": 240, \"stitched\": 1, \"width\": 128, \"height\": 880, \"thumb_height\": 72, \"url\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=WllhvcRH3KM,8tHOVVgGkpk,wvJAgrUBF4w,1yaqUI4b974,hq8j86OenqM,xVyYcAI90jw,vZaRgMOo-Ig,dMuGAmdr8m4,uENITui5_jU,hSorsJ-lRYk,kf1xFCcvadg\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=c99tZpvMiwZDzKB_NwFL5pdZ3QM\", \"thumb_width\": 120}, \"related_feature\": \"relmfu\", \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/1yaqUI4b974\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=tOEOMdumSWc1G--uyQNZJ1_r1HY\", \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\", \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=1yaqUI4b974\\u0026feature=relmfu\", \"encrypted_id\": \"1yaqUI4b974\", \"public_name\": \"brusspup\"}, {\"duration\": \"1:24\", \"view_count\": \"840,664\", \"title\": \"335-foot 700 Ton Ship Flips\", \"thumbnail_info\": {\"posx\": 0, \"posy\": 320, \"stitched\": 1, \"width\": 128, \"height\": 880, \"thumb_height\": 72, \"url\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=WllhvcRH3KM,8tHOVVgGkpk,wvJAgrUBF4w,1yaqUI4b974,hq8j86OenqM,xVyYcAI90jw,vZaRgMOo-Ig,dMuGAmdr8m4,uENITui5_jU,hSorsJ-lRYk,kf1xFCcvadg\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=c99tZpvMiwZDzKB_NwFL5pdZ3QM\", \"thumb_width\": 120}, \"related_feature\": \"related\", \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/hq8j86OenqM\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=Go1pp4c_d6887ErOHp0rEfAsGoU\", \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\", \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=hq8j86OenqM\\u0026feature=related\", \"encrypted_id\": \"hq8j86OenqM\", \"public_name\": \"Rick Scheu\"}, {\"duration\": \"1:18\", \"view_count\": \"400,264\", \"title\": \"Ashending against gravity by Kokichi Sugihara\", \"thumbnail_info\": {\"posx\": 0, \"posy\": 400, \"stitched\": 1, \"width\": 128, \"height\": 880, \"thumb_height\": 72, \"url\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=WllhvcRH3KM,8tHOVVgGkpk,wvJAgrUBF4w,1yaqUI4b974,hq8j86OenqM,xVyYcAI90jw,vZaRgMOo-Ig,dMuGAmdr8m4,uENITui5_jU,hSorsJ-lRYk,kf1xFCcvadg\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=c99tZpvMiwZDzKB_NwFL5pdZ3QM\", \"thumb_width\": 120}, \"related_feature\": \"related\", \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/xVyYcAI90jw\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=gmPmiN0TY7CtOOafAxsBQYC-CuE\", \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\", \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=xVyYcAI90jw\\u0026feature=related\", \"encrypted_id\": \"xVyYcAI90jw\", \"public_name\": \"Gianluigi Filippelli\"}, {\"duration\": \"0:55\", \"view_count\": \"573,904\", \"title\": \"Sold! Nadex Coin Sorter Counter\", \"thumbnail_info\": {\"posx\": 0, \"posy\": 480, \"stitched\": 1, \"width\": 128, \"height\": 880, \"thumb_height\": 72, \"url\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=WllhvcRH3KM,8tHOVVgGkpk,wvJAgrUBF4w,1yaqUI4b974,hq8j86OenqM,xVyYcAI90jw,vZaRgMOo-Ig,dMuGAmdr8m4,uENITui5_jU,hSorsJ-lRYk,kf1xFCcvadg\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=c99tZpvMiwZDzKB_NwFL5pdZ3QM\", \"thumb_width\": 120}, \"related_feature\": \"related\", \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/vZaRgMOo-Ig\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=m3COC6q6y7FXbBlzpYCkCEEQJjI\", \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\", \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=vZaRgMOo-Ig\\u0026feature=related\", \"encrypted_id\": \"vZaRgMOo-Ig\", \"public_name\": \"Curtis Zeisler\"}, {\"duration\": \"4:57\", \"view_count\": \"337,612\", \"title\": \"How To Solve A Rubik's Cube (No Memorization) - Part 1\\\/4\", \"thumbnail_info\": {\"posx\": 0, \"posy\": 560, \"stitched\": 1, \"width\": 128, \"height\": 880, \"thumb_height\": 72, \"url\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=WllhvcRH3KM,8tHOVVgGkpk,wvJAgrUBF4w,1yaqUI4b974,hq8j86OenqM,xVyYcAI90jw,vZaRgMOo-Ig,dMuGAmdr8m4,uENITui5_jU,hSorsJ-lRYk,kf1xFCcvadg\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=c99tZpvMiwZDzKB_NwFL5pdZ3QM\", \"thumb_width\": 120}, \"related_feature\": \"related\", \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/dMuGAmdr8m4\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=fwyZkY1zLp5hrS1PTh9qd7d4hmA\", \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\", \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=dMuGAmdr8m4\\u0026feature=related\", \"encrypted_id\": \"dMuGAmdr8m4\", \"public_name\": \"Philip Brocoum\"}, {\"duration\": \"2:17\", \"view_count\": \"6,678,361\", \"title\": \"Amazing Water \\u0026 Sound Experiment #2\", \"thumbnail_info\": {\"posx\": 0, \"posy\": 640, \"stitched\": 1, \"width\": 128, \"height\": 880, \"thumb_height\": 72, \"url\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=WllhvcRH3KM,8tHOVVgGkpk,wvJAgrUBF4w,1yaqUI4b974,hq8j86OenqM,xVyYcAI90jw,vZaRgMOo-Ig,dMuGAmdr8m4,uENITui5_jU,hSorsJ-lRYk,kf1xFCcvadg\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=c99tZpvMiwZDzKB_NwFL5pdZ3QM\", \"thumb_width\": 120}, \"related_feature\": \"relmfu\", \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/uENITui5_jU\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=3V07FkPBElUksqkiE6jhgR5mv_o\", \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\", \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=uENITui5_jU\\u0026feature=relmfu\", \"encrypted_id\": \"uENITui5_jU\", \"public_name\": \"brusspup\"}, {\"duration\": \"1:37\", \"view_count\": \"1,352,850\", \"title\": \"Liquid Stacking! (How To)\", \"thumbnail_info\": {\"posx\": 0, \"posy\": 720, \"stitched\": 1, \"width\": 128, \"height\": 880, \"thumb_height\": 72, \"url\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=WllhvcRH3KM,8tHOVVgGkpk,wvJAgrUBF4w,1yaqUI4b974,hq8j86OenqM,xVyYcAI90jw,vZaRgMOo-Ig,dMuGAmdr8m4,uENITui5_jU,hSorsJ-lRYk,kf1xFCcvadg\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=c99tZpvMiwZDzKB_NwFL5pdZ3QM\", \"thumb_width\": 120}, \"related_feature\": \"relmfu\", \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/hSorsJ-lRYk\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=LePBch42wY_Icephs7Yhw5R91BU\", \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\", \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=hSorsJ-lRYk\\u0026feature=relmfu\", \"encrypted_id\": \"hSorsJ-lRYk\", \"public_name\": \"brusspup\"}, {\"duration\": \"0:56\", \"view_count\": \"3,869,695\", \"title\": \"Amazing Swimming Pool Illusion!\", \"thumbnail_info\": {\"posx\": 0, \"posy\": 800, \"stitched\": 1, \"width\": 128, \"height\": 880, \"thumb_height\": 72, \"url\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=WllhvcRH3KM,8tHOVVgGkpk,wvJAgrUBF4w,1yaqUI4b974,hq8j86OenqM,xVyYcAI90jw,vZaRgMOo-Ig,dMuGAmdr8m4,uENITui5_jU,hSorsJ-lRYk,kf1xFCcvadg\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=c99tZpvMiwZDzKB_NwFL5pdZ3QM\", \"thumb_width\": 120}, \"related_feature\": \"relmfu\", \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http:\\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/kf1xFCcvadg\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=C1aCdkCphemgOJChXG0f43WVoeU\", \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\", \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=kf1xFCcvadg\\u0026feature=relmfu\", \"encrypted_id\": \"kf1xFCcvadg\", \"public_name\": \"brusspup\"}]}, \"result\": \"ok\", \"signed_in_username\": \"\", \"build_signature\": \"en:900375,900382,900816,904494,904497,906001,906842,906942,906945,907231,907724,908536,909549,912711,913428,913563,919373,919811,920302,924606,925714,925718,925720,925722,925726,929117,929121,929127,929129,929131,929906,929907,929917,929922,929930,929933,930803,931924,934507,936308,936310,936312,936403,938701,939903\", \"build_id\": 0}";
```

Comment: use json_decode($str);  this will give you an array

Comment: This is certainly not valid JSON

Comment: How can i convert this to a valid json. My actuval task is to retrieve   a url from this.

Comment: remove the first 3 characters, then you'll get an stdClass object by `json_decode`

Answer (score 2):

The string is not valid `JSON` - The first few characters `)]}'` - Considering you have manually created the string, you can just remove them and then use `json_decode`

```
var_dump(json_decode($str));
```

Or dynamically using `substr()`

```
json_decode(substr($str, 4));
```